# Read a Json file through a json script and display it in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I am a newbie to web and js programming so my issue might be simple.
I have found a piece code which allows me to create a calendar with all the rendez-vous in it.
The rendez-vous data are formatted into Json data and read through a JS script.

Here is the code :

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var data=
[
    {
      "title": "Rdv M.Ba",
      "start": "2020-02-04T10:00:00"

    },
    {
      "title": "Rdv M. Dia",
      "start": "2020-02-07T16:00:00",
      "end": "2020-02-07T16:15:00"
    }
  ];
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
  },
  defaultDate: '2020-02-12',
  editable: true,
  navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  events: data
});
calendar.render();
});
</script>
```

This way it is working but as soon as I replace the variable "data" in the script with that var rdv = require('./rdv.json'); (as you may have guessed rdv.json contains the exact same infos as the Json in var data with the same format) it does not display anything.
So could you tell me what is wrong here?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello, you'd need to share some of your code to expand your question and give us something to work with. The ideal would be example data of the `rdv.json` file to give us an idea of the data structure. And also, the initialization script for your calendar. And if it shows something you should also add if there are any console errors.

Comment: Not sure what you'r setup is exactly but you can't do `require('./rdv.json')` on the web unless you have some sort of a build tool that will convert import/require statements into something that browsers can understand. Show us your code and explain aexactly what you're using (setup) then we will be able to help

Comment: Make sure you aren't following instructions for Node.js when you're not using Node.js.

Comment: Sorry I had some issues to display the code as I am a newbie here. I have now added the piece of code.

Comment: @Developer if that's all you have with no setup/build process (`webpack` or `parcel`), then the `require` statement won't work. If you want that you should look into frontend build tools since this doesn't work out of the box in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out in the comments `require('./rdv.json')` isn't standard javascript as found in the browser by default. You may be confused with `nodejs` or some other javascript framework. 
A way to solve your question is adapted from [here](https://www.geekstrick.com/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript/) and is as follows:

```js
function loadJSON(callback) {
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open('GET', './rdv.json', true);
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {

      callback(xobj.responseText);
    }
  };
  xobj.send(null);
}
```

Here we have created a function that can load the `rdv.json` file as *real* `json`. Since it is a callback function, you should be able use the data as follows:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    loadJSON(function(response) {

        data = JSON.parse(response);

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
           plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
           header: {
               left: 'prev,next today',
               center: 'title',
               right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
           },
           defaultDate: '2020-02-12',
           editable: true,
           navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
           eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
           events: data
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
});
```

Hope this answer helps you!